# Разница дат MomentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Нигде не смог найти как при вычитании из одной даты другой получить сколько прошло полных лет, полных месяцев и полных дней. По отдельности посчитать не проблема, а можно ли как-то вывести разницу сразу в формате 'N лет N месяцев N дней' учитывая?

```
var oneD = moment('11.10.2005'); 
var TwoD= moment('15.11.2025'); 
var duration = moment.duration(TwoD.diff(oneD));
var years = ~~duration.asYears();
var months = ~~duration.asMonths() - years*12;
var allD = years + ' лет ' + months + ' месяцев';
```

Comment: покажите ваше решение (ваш код)

Comment: У меня есть решение только для N лет N месяцев. Как сделать с днями пока не разобрался

Comment: опубликуйте то, что есть. Вам нужно показать как вы самостоятельно пытались решить задачу.

Comment: var oneD = moment('11.10.2005'); 
var TwoD= moment('15.11.2025'); 
var duration = moment.duration(TwoD.diff(oneD));
var years = ~~duration.asYears();
var months = ~~duration.asMonths() - years*12;
var allD = years + ' лет ' + months + ' месяцев';

Comment: не в комментарии, опубликуйте в тексте вопроса Ваш код

Comment: Добавил в текст вопроса

Comment: **[Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = moment([2025, 11, 15]);
var b = moment([2005, 10, 11]);

var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
b.add(years, 'years');

var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
b.add(months, 'months');

var days = a.diff(b, 'days');

console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[@Оригинал ответа на so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988284/5398808)